# CSS z-index issue top menu background

Tags: html, css

I try to display a cloud as background on my menu, it actually gets displayed (just a little part) but it's hidden by the menu background. I had applied z-index on both items but it's not working.

The CSS code I'm using is :

```
    /*** ESSENTIAL STYLES ***/
.sf-contener {
clear: both;
}
.sf-right {
  margin-right: 14px;
  float: right;
  width: 7px;
}
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
list-style: none;
}
.sf-menu {
margin: 10px 0;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
width:980px;/* 980 */
background: #383838;
}
.sf-menu ul {
position: absolute;
top: -999em;
width: 10em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) */
}
.sf-menu ul li {
width: 100%;
}
.sf-menu li:hover {
visibility: inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}
.sf-menu li {
float: left;
position: relative;
top: 0;
/*border-right: 1px solid #777;*/
}
.sf-menu a {
display: block;
position: relative;
color:#fff;
}
.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
left: 0;
/*padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;*/
top: 35px; /* match top ul list item height */
z-index: 99;
width:auto;
}
ul.sf-menu li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover li ul {
top: -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}
ul.sf-menu li li:hover li ul,
ul.sf-menu li li.sfHover li ul {
top: -999em;
}
ul.sf-menu li li li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li li li.sfHover ul {
left: 200px; /* match ul width */
top: 0;
}


/*** DEMO SKIN ***/
.cat-title {
display: none;
}
.sf-menu {
float: left;
margin-bottom: -2em;
width: 100%;
height: 75px;
background: url('http://www.fdsfs.com/themes/fdfds/img/cabecera.png') repeat left center; 
z-index: 100;
position:relative;
}
.sf-menu a {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  display:block;
    margin-right:2px;
    padding: 0 22px 0 20px;
    line-height:35px;   
    border: 10;
    text-decoration:none; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family:Handlee;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
color: #916e6e;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.sf-menu li ul {
  border:1px solid #f1b6b1; box-shadow:2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  width:500px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 23px 0px 0px 0px;
  top:0;
  background: white;
}
.sf-menu li li {
background: white; 
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height:35px; 
  line-height:35px; 
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}
.sf-menu li li a {
font-size: 16px;
text-transform: capitalize;
top:0;  
}
.sf-menu li li li {
background: blue;
}
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
   font-weight: bold; 
   color: white;
   background: url('http://www.fds.com/themes/fdsfs/img/boton-b.png') no-repeat center -18px; 
   z-index: 90;
   position:relative;
}
.sf-menu ul li:hover, .sf-menu ul li.sfHover,
.sf-menu ul li a:focus, .sf-menu ul li a:hover, .sf-menu ul li a:active {
background: #eecfd0; //#4e4e4e; 
outline: 0;
} 
/*** arrows **/
.sf-menu a.sf-with-ul {
padding-right:  2.25em;
min-width: 1px; /* trigger IE7 hasLayout so spans position accurately */
}
.sf-sub-indicator {
position: absolute;
display: block;
right: 10px;
top: 1.05em; /* IE6 only */
width: 10px;
height: 35px;
text-indent:  -999em;
overflow: hidden;
background: url('../img/arrows-ffffff.png') no-repeat -10px -100px; /* 8-bit indexed alpha png. IE6 gets solid image only */
}
a > .sf-sub-indicator {  /* give all except IE6 the correct values */
top: 11px;
background-position: 0 -100px; /* use translucent arrow for modern browsers*/
}
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
background-position: -10px -100px; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}


/* point right for anchors in subs */
.sf-menu ul .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  -10px 0; }
.sf-menu ul a > .sf-sub-indicator { background-position:  0 0; }
/* apply hovers to modern browsers */
.sf-menu ul a:focus > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:hover > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul a:active > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li:hover > a > .sf-sub-indicator,
.sf-menu ul li.sfHover > a > .sf-sub-indicator {
background-position: -10px 0; /* arrow hovers for modern browsers*/
}


/*** shadows for all but IE6 ***/
.sf-shadow ul {
background: url('../img/shadow.png') no-repeat bottom right;
padding: 0 8px 9px 0;
-moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
-moz-border-top-right-radius: 17px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 17px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 17px;
}
.sf-shadow ul.sf-shadow-off {
background: transparent;
}
li.sf-search {
  background: inherit;
  float: right;
  line-height: 25px;
  background:transparent;
}
li.sf-search input {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 18px 6px 0 0;
  background: #fff url('../../../../img/search-zoom3.png') no-repeat left center;
  border:1px solid #777;
}


/* hack IE7 */
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited {height:34px !IE;}
.sf-menu li li {
width:200px;
background:#726f72 !IE;
}

#block_top_menu .category-thumbnail {
  display:none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  float: none; }
  #block_top_menu .category-thumbnail div {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333%; }
    #block_top_menu .category-thumbnail div img {
      max-width: 100%; }
#block_top_menu li.category-thumbnail {
  padding-right: 0; }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please, read carefully: [ask]

Comment: if you're talking about that brown cloud thingy, check its background position on hover

Comment: The position is OK is where I want it to be....but has to be totally visible not hidden by other background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that cloud thingy should be visible completely, the you could:

- add a `padding-top: height-of-cloud-background`(I think its 20px or smthing like that) to the `<a>` tag that has this background
- and pull the `<a>` tab back up by using a `margin-top: negative-height-of-cloud-background`

So basically as far as I see it in your menu:

```
.sf-menu a.sf-with-ul{
    /*extra code stuff*/
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Then again you could use a `:pseudo` class on this specific tag is it fits better.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.